# DynamoDBAttribute with DynamoDbEnhancedAsyncClient not working

Tags: aws-sdk-java-2.0, amazon-dynamodb

Looks like renaming a field with `@DynamoDBAttribute` does not work with the new `DynamoDbEnhancedAsyncClient`.

Entity:

```
@DynamoDbBean
public class TableEntity {
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "unique_id")
    private String id;

    public TableEntity() {
    }

    public TableEntity(String id) {
      this.is = id;
    }

    @DynamoDbPartitionKey
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

DynamoDBAsyncClient:

```
DynamoDbEnhancedAsyncClient dynamoDbAsyncClient = DynamoDbEnhancedAsyncClient.builder().dynamoDbClient(DynamoDbAsyncClient.builder().build()).build();
```

Table:

```
DynamoDbAsyncTable<TableEntity> table =  dynamoDbAsyncClient.table(tableName, TableSchema.fromBean(TableEntity));
```

When I try to `CreatTable`:

```
table.createTable(
    CreateTableEnhancedRequest.builder()
    .provisionedThroughput(
        ProvisionedThroughput.
        builder()
       .readCapacityUnits(2L)
       .writeCapacityUnits(2L)
       .build())
   .build()
).get();
```

I see a table with the field name `id` instead of `unique_id`.

Has anybody solved this or experienced the same issue? I haven't tried with the sync version, but I'm curious if somebody got it working with the sync version, i.e. using `DynamoDbEnhancedClient` and `DynamoDbTable`?

I'm using `software.amazon.awssdk:dynamodb-enhanced:2.17.75` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/master/services-custom/dynamodb-enhanced/README.md#initialization), we need to define a custom schema to make this work. i.e. `DynamoDBAttribute` will not work with the enhanced client. Specifically, use the following `TableEntity` class:

```
static final TableSchema<TableEntity> MY_TABLE_SCHEMA =
  TableSchema.builder(TableEntity.class)
    .newItemSupplier(TableEntity::new)
    .addAttribute(String.class, a -> a.name("unique_id")
                                      .getter(TableEntity::getId)
                                      .setter(TableEntity::setId)
                                      .tags(primaryPartitionKey()));
```

and pass the schema as follows:

`DynamoDbAsyncTable<TableEntity> table = dynamoDbAsyncClient.table(tableName, MY_TABLE_SCHEMA)`;

No changes to `CreateTableRequest` are necessary.